# javascript mostrar un texto diferente en un div según la fecha

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<td class="cpo12"> Santoral de hoy: 
  <strong><b><a href="#openModal">pulsar aquí</a></b></strong> <strong><b><a href="#openModal"></a>
      <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"><a href="#openModal"></a>
        <div><a href="#openModal"></a><a href="#close" title="Close"

            class="close">X</a>
          <h2>Santoral de hoy</h2>
          <p>La Transfiguración de Nuestro Señor Jesucristo.</p>
          <p>Santos Mártires Justo y Pastor; San Hormisdas, Papa y
            Confesor; Santiago, Ermitaño; martirio de doscientos
            monjes con Esteban su Abad; santos Mártires Felicísimo y
            Agapito; san Sixto II, Papa y Mártir.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </b></strong>
 </td>
```

Deseo añadir el santoral del día a mi web. Necesito saber qué código he de escribir para que un div tome los datos .txt según sea el día de la fecha. Es decir, tengo 365 .txt, uno para cada día del año, y deseo que automáticamente se inserte el correspondiente al día de la fecha, y no tener que estar introduciéndolo a las 0:00 horas todos los días.
Gracias por una respuesta rápida.

Comment: y como lo tienes ahora? (muestra el código)

Comment: Acá no damos "respuestas rápidas". Haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: No tengo aún nada, pues ignoro cómo hacerlo. Si tengo puesta una ventana que se abre al pulsar, pero el texto no me cambia:

Comment: <tr>
            <td class="cpo12"> Santoral de hoy: <strong><b><a href="#openModal">pulsar
                    aquí</a></b></strong> <strong><b><a href="#openModal"></a>
                  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"><a href="#openModal"></a>
                    <div><a href="#openModal"></a><a href="#close" title="Close"

                        class="close">X</a>

Comment: <h2>Santoral de hoy</h2>
                      <p>La Transfiguración de Nuestro Señor Jesucristo.</p>
                      <p>Santos Mártires Justo y Pastor; San Hormisdas, Papa y
                        Confesor; Santiago, Ermitaño; martirio de doscientos
                        monjes con Esteban su Abad; santos Mártires Felicísimo y
                        Agapito; san Sixto II, Papa y Mártir.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </b></strong></td>
          </tr>

Comment: No he podido subirlo seguido, pues no me deja.

Comment: Hola Mancipio, bienvenido, te sugiero que elimines los comentarios en donde muestras código, edites tu pregunta y los agregues en ella, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y presiona el botón cuyo icono es `<>`, se abrirá una ventana y en ella coloca donde corresponda el código que tienes y que muestra el mensaje de forma NO dinamica

Comment: @MancipioLimusTurpe haz clic en [edit] y añade el código a la pregunta.

Comment: Una consulta, lo que haces ahora es copiar el código del txt y pegarlo en el HTML??? además, como se llaman eso .txt?

Comment: Gracias, Yussef. Efectivamente, ahora pego el texto que tengo en los .tx en el HTML, cada noche, a las 0:00. Por eso quiero automatizarlo.

Comment: Puedes ver la página en https://amadoresdecristo.org/index.html

Comment: Solo me queda la duda, de que nombres tienen esos .TXT, puedes dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Ejemplo: 07-08-2023.txt

Comment: Yussef, no me funciona. He insertado arriba el código, por si hay algún error. Puedes verlo en la web, también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paso 1:** Debes dejar todos los txt en una carpeta accesible desde internet. Por ejemplo, tu carpeta se llama `santoriales`. Debes poder ver la información si entras a https://amadoresdecristo.org/santoriales/07-08-2023.txt

**Paso 2:** Preparar el HTMl para ingresar contendido dinámico mediante javascript. Básicamente ingresar un elemento con una `id` para determinar donde irá el contenido

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"><a href="#openModal"></a>
  <div><a href="#openModal"></a><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Santoral de hoy</h2>
    <div id="santorial_contenido"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Paso 3:** Generar una función que retorne el nombre del archivo según la fecha

```js
function GetSantorialHoyFile(){
  const f = new Date();
  const d = String(f.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'); //padStart para agregar cero a la izquierda de ser necesario
  const m =  String(f.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0'); //en javascript el primer mes (enero) es el mes cero, por lo que hay que sumar 1
  
  return `${d}-${m}-${f.getFullYear()}.txt`;
}

console.log(GetSantorialHoyFile())
```

**Paso 4:**  Buscar el TXT y cargarlo dentro `santorial_contenido` (lo que hicimos en el paso 2)

```
function GetSantorialHoyFile(){
  const f = new Date();
  const d = String(f.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'); //padStart para agregar cero a la izquierda de ser necesario
  const m =  String(f.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0'); //en javascript el primer mes (enero) es el mes cero, por lo que hay que sumar 1
  
  return `${d}-${m}-${f.getFullYear()}.txt`;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { //evento que se ejecutará cuando se haya cargado la página
 
 const file = GetSantorialHoyFile(); //llamamos a la función del paso 3

 fetch("/santoriales/" + file) //buscamos el archivo, en la carpeta según el paso 1
  .then(resp=>resp.text())
  .then(resp=>{
      const cont = document.getElementById("santorial_contenido"); //buscamos donde cargaremos el contenido según el paso 2
      cont.innerHTML = resp;
   });
});
```

Comment: Lo pongo en práctica enseguida, Yussef, me has hecho un gran favor. Te debo una.

Comment: No me ha funcionado y he tenido que meter los datos a mano, para no dejar vacía la ventana modal. Seguro que algo he copiado mal. Voy a meter el código arriba.

Comment: Ya he logrado que funcione. Lo copié mal. Todo mi culpa.